# Mongodb retry match / if no match try another / aggregation

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregation

What I want to achieve is to match a document with a certain "id" (not "_id") . But if the first match isn't found, then try matching another id. Then match a third "question"-value.
If the first document is matched, the second document should not be matched.

pseudo code:

```
if (first id matched)
  {match question}
else if (match second id)
  {match question}
```

I've tried this

```
     "$match": 
        {
            "$and":
            [   
                {            
                    "$or":[{ "id": 78975 },{ "id": 99 }]
                },
                {
                    "question":{"$exists":True}
                }
            ]
        }
```

But this will potentially match two documents.
Even if I use "{ $limit : 1 }", I can't be sure that the first id wasn't matched, and therefore the second document should not be included.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but consider using $cond aggregation.

Comment: as far as I understand $cond can't do the job. Can you give an example of a $cond solution to solve the pseudo code ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want database search query to stop as soon as any matching condition is found?

Comment: I want to stop when the first id is found, yes. And it should not be if the second id is found first.. it should be prioritized so if the first id is found it stops. If its not found, it searches for the second.